# delete cart condition in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I try to remove `conditions` from `items` in my cart and i get `null` values.

## CODES

`controller`

```
public function removecondition(Request $request, $id) {
        $id = $request->input('proId');
        $conditionName = $request->input('conditionname');
        dd($conditionName, $id);
        // Cart::removeItemCondition($id, $conditionName);
        // Session::flash('success', 'Product condition successfully removed from your cart.');
        // return redirect()->back();
    }
```

`route`

```
Route::get('removecondition/{id}', 'CartController@removecondition')->name('removecondition');
```

`blade`

```
// getting name of condition
<input type="hidden" value="{{$condition->getName()}}" name="conditionname">

// getting item id
<input type="hidden" name="proId" value="{{$item->id}}">

//delete button
<a class="pull-left text-danger" href="{{route('removecondition', $item->id)}}"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
```

### My package documents

Remove Specific Item Condition: Cart::removeItemCondition($itemId, $conditionName)

```
/**
* remove a condition that has been applied on an item that is already on the cart
*
* @param $itemId
* @param $conditionName
* @return bool
*/
Cart::removeItemCondition($itemId, $conditionName)
```

[source](https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart/)

## UPDATE

light version of my blade:

```
@foreach($items as $item)
  {{$item->id}}

  @foreach($item->conditions as $condition)
     {{$condition->getName()}}

     <input type="hidden" value="{{$condition->getName()}}" name="conditionname"> 
                                
     <a class="pull-left text-danger" href="{{route('removecondition', $item->id)}}"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
  @endforeach


  <input type="hidden" name="proId" value="{{$item->id}}">
@endforeach
```

Comment: you obtain both null values for condition and id ?

Comment: yes............

Comment: Should the method be post ? any thoughts

Comment: i'll try.........

Comment: getting `throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($others);` on `route::post`

Comment: Can you add whole form used in the blade

Comment: is so messed up, will be confused, try my best to give you light version of it.

Comment: You have to mention the method post or get in the form as well, not only in the route. That might be an issue

Comment: updated my question.

Comment: Have you checked out the rendered HTML to ensure there is a value for each field?

Comment: yes i checked by inspect

Comment: Please clear your view and route cache, sometime it might cause problem.

Comment: i cleared cach,view,route... no change.

Comment: It seems totally strange problem :D

Comment: :) well it is..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to retrieve the value by using `$request->input('field_name');` because you are not submitting the request using form. I think the best approach for your current code now are like this.

First, change your blade code for < a > tag to

```
<a class="pull-left text-danger" href="{{route('removecondition', ['id' => $item->id, 'condition' => $condition->getName()])}}"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
```

so it will pass both item id and condition in the url, then change your route to

```
Route::get('removecondition/{id}/{condition}', 'CartController@removecondition')->name('removecondition');
```

At last, you may now access the values in your function like this

```
public function removecondition($id, $condition) {
    dd($id, $condition);
}
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Missing required parameters for [Route: removecondition] [URI: removecondition/{id}/{condition}].

Comment: Sorry i missed that. Try to change the href for < a > tag to  `"{{route('removecondition', ['id' => $item->id, 'condition' => $condition->getName()])}}"` updated the code also. @mafortis

Comment: sure, glad can help :)